# Control Snapshot Speed In Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, snapshot

This is for my project. i wrote the code using **getdata** command in matlab.i want to take some snapshots form webcam. But those snapshots are very speed.

I want to slow the snapshot frame. This is the code i written,

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo',3,'RGB24_1600x1200');    
triggerconfig(vid,'manual');   
set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',1);
set(vid,'TriggerRepeat', Inf);
start(vid);
for i=1:2
    trigger(vid);
    im=getdata(vid,1);
    figure,imshow(im);
end
imwrite(im,'web.jpg');
stop(vid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pause(n)` in your `for` loop, which pauses execution for `n` seconds before continuing. For example `pause(0.1)`.